# Need a formal proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If  A and B are two equipotent sets (they have 1-1 correspondence). Prove that if A is denumerable then B is also denumerable.
It is easy to understand by intuition. But I can't understand how to prove it formally.

Comment: You have to apply the *definitions*: *denumerable* means (but check on your textbook for details) there is a $1-1$ correspondence with $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is denumerable there is a biiection $f \colon \mathbb N \to A$. By hypothesis there is a biiection $g\colon A \to B$, since composition of biiection is a biiection we have that $g \circ f \colon \mathbb N \to B$ is a biiection too, hence $B$ is denumerable.

Comment: what if : B is non denumerable and we need to show A is non denumerable. Provided A and B have same cardinality.

Comment: Can it go like this ? Suppose A is denumerable. But since A~B that means B is also denumerable , which contradicts our hypothesis 'B is non denumerable'. So we conclude A is non denumerable.

Comment: @HumaJamil your argument is perfectly sound :)